# How can I handle multiple values with file_get_contents('php://input');

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services

I have a web service which handle only one value.
Is it possible (and how) to handle multiple values for a mySQL query with multiple placeholders (but different values for each)?

Here's the web service:

```
<?php
    $newSongwriter = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $url = "127.0.0.1";
    $database = "songs";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    
    $connect = mysqli_connect($url, $username, $password, $database);   
    
    if(!$connect) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: ".$connect->connect_error);
    }
    
    //create a template
    $sql = "INSERT INTO songwriter (songwriter) VALUES (?);";
  
    
    //create a prepared statement
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
    
    
    //prepare the prepared statement
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "SQL statement failed";
    } else {
        //bind parameters to the placeholders
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $newSongwriter);      //1 strings, is equal to newSongwriter
        //run parameters inside database
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
?>
```

I know how to do the stuff with like `bind_param($stmt, "sss", $newSongwriter $otherValue, $aThirdValue);` and that I have to use more placeholders in the prepared statement. But how can I get more then one value passed?

Comment: It depends on how the values are passed to the service

Comment: A common way to do this is to require the input to be in JSON format.

Comment: You could use JSON, or CSV, or XML, or a list of items one on each line, or joined with the word "and", or really whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you all a lot! Can you show how it would look like if I use JSON? Or do you have any useful links?